# Access to undeclared static property $this

Tags: php

This is my class:

```
Class RUNcookieDescutes Extends DF_CookiesDescutes
{

   function RUNcookieDescutes($Cookietype)
   {

      // parent the faiamal father object
      parent::$this->EachDescute = array("fsr" => array(0,1), // order by date                  
                                         "prf" => array(0,1,5,10,15), // refrech page url
                                         "ths" => array(0,1), // type of signature
                                         "tps" => array(10,30,50,70), // size of reply pages
                                         "por" => array(0,1), // order by reply or not
                                         "psa" => array(0,1,2), // find the display fined
                                         "pfr" => array("absulot")); // selected forums posts
      // parent the faiamal father object
      if ($Cookietype == 0)
      {
         parent::findElementsDescuteCookie();
      }
      else
      {
         parent::findElementsDescuteSession();
      }
   }

}
```

The error I receive is this:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DF_CookiesDescutes::$this in C:\xampp\htdocs\cp_inc\class_object.php on line 441

Comment: You can't call a static property mixing dynamic syntax, also you can't ask question in this sloppy way.

Comment: I disagree with these close votes. This question does include *a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*.

Comment: What is the definition of DF_CookiesDescutes ?

Comment: @AliNew replace `parent::$this` with just `$this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is:

> Access to undeclared static property: DF_CookiesDescutes::$this

In your code:

```
parent::$this->EachDescute
```

You can't use this syntax. If you want get/set `EachDescute` class property you have to use:

```
$this->EachDescute;
```

If the `EachDescute` is set as `private`, you can't get/set it from extended class.

The keyword `parent::` is used to call a method of parent class (in extended class).

**You can't use `parent::` keyword to set a property (variable).**