# Access to undeclared static property

Tags: php, static-methods

My code snippet:

```
public static function saveEntryView($content, $conf, $m_name, $m_firstname, $m_street, $m_zipcity, $m_phone, $m_email, $m_rooms, $m_etage, $m_wohnberechtigungsschein, $m_member, $m_mieter, $m_termin, $m_size, $m_msg ) 
{


    self::$conf['template'] = '/home/www/p422082/html/typo3/fileadmin/wgkw/templates/wgkwcontactform.html';
```

Before I had:

```
$this->$conf['template'] = '/home/www/p422082/html/typo3/fileadmin/wgkw/templates/wgkwcontactform.html';
```

Which basically says that I'm calling non-static object in a static function and  gave me this error(totally fair):

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

And led me to following topic [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)
and there I've found that it can be changed to:

```
self::$conf['template'] = '/home/www/p422082/html/typo3/fileadmin/wgkw/templates/wgkwcontactform.html';
```

But it gives me Access to undeclared static property: $conf error.

Which led me to this topic: [Access to undeclared static property $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350763/access-to-undeclared-static-property-this)

which is basically going back to the beggining where the problem has started and this has left me quite confused. Appreciate any help/tips.

Comment: When defining ``$conf`` instance variable you need to make it static, i.e. ``private static $conf``.

Comment: This would give me syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)

Comment: Could you post how you define your class and how you declare ``$conf``.

Comment: Try setting your function without static in it like this: `public function saveEntryView(args here)`, and revert to your first object property call `$this->$conf['template']`

Comment: @alistaircol It's like this: public static function saveEntryView($content, $conf, ...)

Comment: @DenisSolakovic It starts complaining at the next line PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty and I guess I have to dig into that one now.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): thing in. But try to sort it out first XD

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve. Don’t you simply want to define a [static property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties)?